# How to execute a YUI function from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, yui3

How can i call a YUI function that is wrapped inside a YUI().use from javascript?

example
Below is a YUI function "runShowAnim" which executes animShow.run(); for an animation effect...

```
 var runShowAnim = function(e) {
     animShow.run();
 };
```

I want this effect to happen when i validate something in a javascript function. I tried to call it as below. But it doesn't seem to work.

```
function notifyUser(message) {
   document.getElementById("msgArea").innerHTML = message;
   runShowAnim();
}
```

Comment: You mean runShowAnim **()** right (with the parantheses)?

Answer (score 2):

I achieved this by sandwiching the YUI function completely inside a function and calling that function..

```
var runShowAnim = function() { 
    YUI().use('anim', 'node', function(Y) {
        var animShow = new Y.Anim({
        node: '#msgArea',
        to: { height: 50,opacity:1 }
        });
        animShow.run();
    });
};
```

now i can call runShowAnim without any problem like in the below sample function..

```
function notifyUser(message) { 
   document.getElementById("msgArea").innerHTML = message; 
   runShowAnim(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a function, you have to suffix the function name with `()` and include 0 or more comma separated arguments between them.

```
runShowAnim();
```

If the function doesn't have global scope (as yours will have if it is declared inside a function passed to `use()`) and not passed outside in some way then you can only do this from the same scope.

Comment: I think scope is a problem for me. How can i make a function inside YUI().use('anim', 'node', function(Y) { <function is present over here> }); have global scope?

Answer (score 0):

**I think you're missing the parentheses.**

```
function notifyUser(message) {
   document.getElementById("msgArea").innerHTML = message;
   runShowAnim(); // right here
}
```

Comment: I have the parentheses. Missed to put them in the question while I was putting just the required bits. The error I get is that the function runShowAnim is not defined

Comment: Are they defined in the same scope?

Answer (score 0):

YUI.thefunction()?

I think you need to call it with namespace too

something similar to

```
var X = function(){};
X.Y = function(){};
X.Y.Z = function(){};
X.Y.Z.foo = function(e){alert(e);}

//foo("me");<-error

X.Y.Z.foo("me");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a function that has been defined inside the closure (the function passed as the last parameter to YUI.use) from outside it, you need to expose the function globally.

Either define a global variable outside the closure and assign your function to it, or assign your function to the window object

i.e.

```
var runShowAnim;

YUI().use(function(e){
  runShowAnim = function(){alert('called');}
});

runShowAnim();
```